# Writing a column function in power query that sums a value with the value one row above the same column I am creating

Tags: if-statement, recursion, powerquery

Hi I'm currently in the process of converting a excel formula into power query and I'm running into some trouble. The idea is quite simple, but I'm having trouble getting the formula to work because power query does not support recursion.

This is what my original excel formula reads:

```
IF(AND[@[less than year]]<=EOMONTH([@[Month]],0),[@[id]]=C2,[@[MaxCap]]+P2,IF(AND([@[less than year]]<=EOMONTH([@[Month]],0),[@[id]]<>C2,[@[MaxCap]],0)
```

- Column C is id number
- MaxCap is a decimal number in column I.
- Less than Year is a date in column O.
- Month is a date in column G.
- Column P is a column called Sum

  - this is where the formula sits.
- Row 2 is one row above the reference cell (row 3)

Basically it checks if the date from Less than Year is less than the end of month of month and the ID is the same as one row above. If true, take the sum of the MaxCap from the current row with the Sum Value one row above (p2). If false, check the date condition again and if the ID is not the same as the one above, if true, return MaxCap, if false return 0.

This is what I have in Power Query, I created a new column called Sum and the formula is shown below

```
if [less than year] <= Date.EndofMonth([Month]) 
   and [id] = #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[id] 
   then [MaxCap] + #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Sum]
   else if [less than year] <= Date.EndofMonth([Month]) 
     and [id] <> #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[id] 
     then [MaxCap] 
     else 0
```

What happened was values that flowed into [MaxCap] + "Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Sum] triggered an Error because it couldnt read the [Sum] column. The other part of the formula was fine.

Im not sure how to rewrite this formula at this point, any assistance is appreciated.

Sample Data

```
EMPID   RCD ID  FIRSTNAME   EMP LASTNAME    CALC GROUP  Month   TOTAL WORK HOURS    MaxCap  Anniversary BUSINESS TITLE  Grade   Grade Value Start Day   less than year  Sum
12345   0   12345-0 First Name  Last Name   C   2023-09-01  144.91  144.91  8-5-2023    Basketball Player   B1  1   2022-7-11   2022-7-11   2028.76
12345   0   12345-0 First Name  Last Name   C   2023-10-01  84  84  8-5-2023    Basketball Player   B1  1   2022-7-11   2022-7-11   2112.76
12345   0   12345-0 First Name  Last Name   C   2023-11-01  134.62  134.62  8-5-2023    Basketball Player   B1  1   2022-7-11   2022-7-11   2247.38
12345   0   12345-0 First Name  Last Name   C   2023-12-01  144.25  144.25  8-5-2023    Basketball Player   B1  1   2022-7-11   2022-7-11   2391.63
12345   0   12345-0 First Name  Last Name   C   2024-01-01  120.67  120.67  8-5-2023    Basketball Player   B1  1   2022-7-11   2022-7-11   2512.3
12345   0   12345-0 First Name  Last Name   C   2024-02-01  62.83   62.83   8-5-2023    Basketball Player   B1  1   2022-7-11   2022-7-11   2575.13
```

This data will be loaded into power query where the Sum column is deleted and created with the formula above.

Then result will be the same as the data table i provided.

The problem is as horseyride mentioned " If Sum is the name of the column you are creating, then you can't have the formula to create that column refer to itself ." Is there a another way to get the same result without running into this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a data sample **as text** which can be copy/pasted, along with a screenshot of the expected results from that same data. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And, by the way, you can write recursive functions in PQ.

Comment: If Sum is the name of the column you are creating, then you can't have the formula to create that column refer to itself .  As Ron says, post sample data, sample desired output, and description of how to get from one to another

Comment: sample data and additional comments added below

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you want is a Running Total of Max Cap for each ID.

I have no idea what you your date consideration is supposed to be since all of your `less than year` dates are well prior to any of the `month` dates, and all of your `less than year` dates are the same. But it may be possible to bring the dates into the grouping by adding a column that creates the date groups you are looking for.

Also, I see no way the `SUM` column in your example can be derived from that example, but I'll assume that is incorrect.

To add a Running Total column to your table, based just on the `ID` column, you

- Group by ID

  - therefore there is no now need to check preceding or next `ID` columns.
- In the Advanced Editor, create a custom aggregation using `List.Generate` which can refer to previous rows in the same column.

The code would look something like:

```
 #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Previous Step", {"ID"}, {
        {"Sum", (t)=> let 
            #"Running Total" = List.Generate(
                ()=>[rt=t[MaxCap]{0}, idx=0],
                each [idx] < Table.RowCount(t),
                each [rt = [rt]+t[MaxCap]{[idx]+1}, idx = [idx]+1],
                each [rt]),
            #"Add Sum Column" = Table.FromColumns(
                Table.ToColumns(t)
                & {#"Running Total"}, Table.ColumnNames(t) & {"Sum"})
            in 
                #"Add Sum Column" 
                ,type table [EMPID=nullable number, RCD=nullable number, ID=nullable text, FIRSTNAME=nullable text, 
                    LASTNAME=nullable text, CALC GROUP=nullable text, Month=nullable date, TOTAL WORK HOURS=nullable number, 
                    MaxCap=nullable number, Anniversary=nullable number, BUSINESS TITLE=nullable text, 
                    Grade=nullable text, Grade Value=nullable number, Start Day=nullable date, 
                    less than year=nullable date, Sum=nullable number] }}),
```

You'd then expand the table (except for the ID colum which is already there).

If you can provide examples of what you are trying to do with the date filter,  that can certainly be added to the custom aggregation.

Using your posted example

| EMPID | RCD | ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | CALC GROUP | Month | TOTAL WORK HOURS | MaxCap | Anniversary | BUSINESS TITLE | Grade | Grade Value | Start Day | less than year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 0 | 12345-0 | First Name | Last Name | C | 9/1/2023 | 144.91 | 144.91 | 8/5/2023 | Basketball Player | B1 | 1 | 7/11/2022 | 7/11/2022 |
| 12345 | 0 | 12345-0 | First Name | Last Name | C | 10/1/2023 | 84 | 84 | 8/5/2023 | Basketball Player | B1 | 1 | 7/11/2022 | 7/11/2022 |
| 12345 | 0 | 12345-0 | First Name | Last Name | C | 11/1/2023 | 134.62 | 134.62 | 8/5/2023 | Basketball Player | B1 | 1 | 7/11/2022 | 7/11/2022 |
| 12345 | 0 | 12345-0 | First Name | Last Name | C | 12/1/2023 | 144.25 | 144.25 | 8/5/2023 | Basketball Player | B1 | 1 | 7/11/2022 | 7/11/2022 |
| 12345 | 0 | 12345-0 | First Name | Last Name | C | 1/1/2024 | 120.67 | 120.67 | 8/5/2023 | Basketball Player | B1 | 1 | 7/11/2022 | 7/11/2022 |
| 12345 | 0 | 12345-0 | First Name | Last Name | C | 2/1/2024 | 62.83 | 62.83 | 8/5/2023 | Basketball Player | B1 | 1 | 7/11/2022 | 7/11/2022 |

and this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table36"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"EMPID", Int64.Type}, {"RCD", Int64.Type}, {"ID", type text}, {"FIRSTNAME", type text}, 
        {"LASTNAME", type text}, {"CALC GROUP", type text}, {"Month", type date}, 
        {"TOTAL WORK HOURS", type number}, {"MaxCap", type number}, {"Anniversary", Int64.Type}, 
        {"BUSINESS TITLE", type text}, {"Grade", type text}, {"Grade Value", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Start Day", type date}, {"less than year", type date}}),
   
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {
        {"Sum", (t)=> let 
            #"Running Total" = List.Generate(
                ()=>[rt=t[MaxCap]{0}, idx=0],
                each [idx] < Table.RowCount(t),
                each [rt = [rt]+t[MaxCap]{[idx]+1}, idx = [idx]+1],
                each [rt]),
            #"Add Sum Column" = Table.FromColumns(
                Table.ToColumns(t)
                & {#"Running Total"}, Table.ColumnNames(t) & {"Sum"})
            in 
                #"Add Sum Column" 
                ,type table [EMPID=nullable number, RCD=nullable number, ID=nullable text, FIRSTNAME=nullable text, 
                    LASTNAME=nullable text, CALC GROUP=nullable text, Month=nullable date, TOTAL WORK HOURS=nullable number, 
                    MaxCap=nullable number, Anniversary=nullable number, BUSINESS TITLE=nullable text, 
                    Grade=nullable text, Grade Value=nullable number, Start Day=nullable date, 
                    less than year=nullable date, Sum=nullable number] }}),


    #"Expanded Sum" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Sum", List.RemoveItems(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),{"ID"}) & {"Sum"})
in
    #"Expanded Sum"
```

Here are the results with the Sum Column
[image]